# AJAX form not submitting Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had similar code working when I created a new button with an .on('click') event, but I am required to use the button that comes with the form. I've added these lines to the initializer:

```
var options =
        {
            data:
            {
                    "create": _this.toBeCreated,
                    "update": _this.toBeUpdated,
                    "destroy": _this.toBeDeleted
            },
            dataType: 'script',
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'custom_statuses/modify_statuses'
        };

        $(_this.delegator.$target.find(".UIForm")[0]).ajaxForm(options);
```

This code semi-works, because if I plug in hard-coded values into the data, I get them returned in the AJAX call.

However, when I try to use these Javascript arrays (which I confirm are not empty), only the last element gets pushed out via AJAX.

For example:

```
toBeDeleted = [1,5,9,7];
```

Should return:

```
"delete": [1,5,9,7]
```

Actually returns:

```
"delete": "7"
```

I don't know what's wrong but, again, this code was working with an .on(click) attached to a button previously. It looked similar:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'custom_statuses/modify_statuses',
            dataType: 'script',
            data:
            {
                "create": _this.toBeCreated,
                "update": _this.toBeUpdated,
                "destroy": _this.toBeDeleted
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had a similar issue using javascript arrays. If you don't implicitly need an array, I got good results using the toSting() method.

Comment: Did you check the XMLHttpRequest to see if it actually uses a PUT request, as you don't see those very often, and all though they are supported (in most browsers), the ajaxform plugin could have this defined as a POST or GET internally ?

Comment: @ErmSo if I use .toString(), the output becomes "", instead of the last element of the array X_X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I need to include brackets in data block:

```
"create[]": _this.toBeCreated,
"update[]": _this.toBeUpdated,
"destroy[]": _this.toBeDeleted
```

I don't know how to indicate an array of arrays though. Update is an array of arrays. "update[[]]" doesn't work.